# CSS, keeping them on one line in spite of the container

Tags: html, css, position

I am trying to do a responsive design with a slider. I have to keep these images on one line even though they have a container div. I need this for doing slider properly. I am thinking of remove the container class but how can I center if I remove the container?

Here is the fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/smtjZ/

```
 <div id="middle">
     <div class="container">
        <div id="works">
           <h3>LATEST WORKS</h3>
              <div id="workslider">


<!-- workslideritem -->
<div class="workslideritem">
<a href="#"><img src="images/workslideritem.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</div>
<!-- workslideritem -->




              </div>  
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Container div has `max-width:1000px` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were using `white-space` on the items instead of on the container.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/smtjZ/1/)

```
#workslider
{
    margin-top:20px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.workslideritem
{
    display:inline-block;
    width:20%;
    margin-right:4%;
    position:relative;
}
```